# Python Can't get the 2 decimal place value to work using the "round" or "format" methods

Tags: python

I've tried different methods in order to get this to work, but it's not changing the value as expected.

```
for i in Lev1_clean_text:
    l = word_tokenize(i)
    c = Counter(category for token in l for category in parse(token))
    key_percent = [(i, round(c[i], 2) / len(l) * 100) for i in c]
    print(key_percent)
```

I've also tried changing this line below, but it's still not giving me the desired effect.

```
key_percent = [(i, int('{:2}'.format(c[i])) / len(l) * 100) for i in c]
```

Desired effect:

```
[('Hedge', 19.23), ('Absolute', 7.69)]
[('Negative', 12.5), ('Curses', 12.50), ('Hedge', 12.50), ('Absolute', 8.33)]
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
[('Hedge', 19.230769230769234), ('Absolute', 7.6923076923076925)]
[('Negative', 12.5), ('Curses', 12.5), ('Hedge', 12.5), ('Absolute', 8.333333333333332)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only rounding `c[i]`, whereas you should round the final number:

```
round(c[i] / len(l) * 100, 2)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right I missed that. Thank you so much. I've been stuck on this problem for a while now. LOL

Comment: Note: This will still output only one decimal point when the second would be `0`. You'd need to use string formatting operations if you wanted to output an exact number of decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

assume **c[i]** is **123.45123** and **len(l)** is **1234**.

then **round(c[i], 2)** is **123.45**

so **round(c[i], 2)** / **len(l)** is **123.45/1234**,and the result is **0.10004051863857374**

obvious your expression is fault!

the right expression is

```
round(c[i]/len(l)*100, 2)
```